# Google Mock: Issue when mocking a C++ class with several levels of inheritance

Tags: c++, unit-testing, inheritance, googletest, googlemock

I'm quite new to testing code using mock so I need some help to resolve my issue. I am developing mocks with GoogleTest and GoogleMock, and the code I need to test is very complex (moreover I cannot copy-paste any part of it to illustrate my issue). I cannot change the code to make it more simple.

My problem is that I need to make unitary tests using mocks but the code I need to test is object-oriented and event-oriented, and has multiple levels of inheritance (at least 7 or 8: A inherits B which inherits C which inherits D and so on).

What I want to do is to make unit tests on A class only. Is there a way to break the inheritance with GoogleMock to only concentrate on A? Right now I have tried to mock all dependencies but I come to the last level and the mock is waiting for an event that will never show up because everything is mocked. That's why I want to "break" this inheritance using mocks.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Maybe create `template <typename T> struct TA : T {/*...*/}; using A = TA<B>; using ATest : TA<BMock>;`.

Comment: You need to provide http://sscce.org/ I understand that you cannot copy code that is owned by your employer - but you can create something that looks like the code you want answer for - change names of classes, functions, get rid of unnecessary implementation details and present it to SO audience - so we will be sure what you want to achieve

Comment: Sorry for the delay.. Some family issues with my little child.. Now I am back to work.. but a lot of changes have been made on code, I need to update my need